# How to call a KSH script from another KSH script

Tags: ksh

I want to call a KSH script a KSH script.

Script 1 performs the following:

1. Loops thru a list of database server
2. Perfroms a query
3. Appends output from query from each database server to a txtfile

Script 2 performs the following:

1. Creates an HTML file that displays the each row in the text file 
      in an HTML File
2. Emails the HTML file with the query results  to a list of receipeints

   Usage: KSH backup_report.ksh qry_rslt_textfile.txt
         (txtfile contains results of query from each server)

Is the following syntax correct?

```
#! /bin/ksh
< Start of Script 1 Code>
.
.
.
< End of Script 1 Code>

< Start of Script 2 Code - Call Script 2>
/sybase/dba/backup_report.ksh qry_rslt_textfile.txt
<End of Script 2 Code>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes - providing that the script has execute permission, this will do what you want. It will in actuality call the second script as the last command of the first script, but that's splitting a technical hair that you're probably not going to need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

To call a script from another program (or script), you must take care of a list of things:

1. The script must be found
2. The script must have execute permissions
3. The script must include a hint to its interpreter

## Finding the script

Check.  You've already included the full path to the script.
An alternative is to include /sybase/dba in the PATH variable at the top of script 1:

```
PATH=/sybase/dba:$PATH
```

## Correct permissions

The script will need execute permissions for all categories of users that may need to run it.

For most interpreters execute permissions are not sufficient; the chosen interpreter also needs to be able to *read* the script's code.

```
$ ls -l  /sybase/dba/backup_report.ksh
-rwxr-x---   1 Henk     sys           805 Apr  3 07:00 /sybase/dba/backup_report.ksh
```

## The right interpreter

Scripts are not executed directly. The kernel needs a hint to tell it which interpreter to use. This is accomplished by including a `#!` (*hashbang*) mark on the first line, followed by the path to the interpreter:

```
#! /bin/ksh
```

Assure you know where your `ksh` lives and insert the right path.

### Final Note

Also make sure you know which version of `ksh`.
These days, `ksh` implies `ksh93`, which is still actively developed and available on most platforms.